# Java - Passing a class to a function

Tags: java, serialization

I'm implementing serialization, and am trying to make everything as modular as possible. When reading objects from files, I'm trying to use just one function to pass everything to an ArrayList, or something of that sort. Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Class1> ReadClass1(String fileName) {
    ArrayList p = null;
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        p = new ArrayList<Class1>();
        while (1 != 2) {
            p.add((Class1) in.readObject());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ;
    }
    
    return p;

}
```

However, I want to read other classes, let's say `Class2` or `Class3`, and right now I'm copy-pasting the code and just editing everything that says "Class1" to "Class2". Is there a way to pass in a specific type I want to use, like this?

```
public static ArrayList<myClass> ReadProducts(String fileName, myClass) { //where myClass is a class
    ArrayList p = null;
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        p = new ArrayList<myClass>();
        while (1 != 2) {
            p.add((myClass) in.readObject());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ;
    }
    
    return p;

}
```

So that I could reuse the function for different classes?

Comment: You might as well write `while(true)`. At least saves a CPU cycle by not having to perform the actual `1 != 2` evaluation every time. This looks like it might result in an infinite loop which gets broken when no more objects are left to read leading to an Exception which you catch. This is not a good approach. You might end up quitting for any Exception and you will not know what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use java [Generics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm). Please find the code below:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> ReadProducts(String fileName, Class<T> t) {
        ArrayList p = null;
        try {
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(
                            new FileInputStream(fileName)));
            p = new ArrayList<T>();

            while (1 != 2) {
                p.add(t.cast(in.readObject()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ;
        }
        return p;
    }
```